# Python web scrape which uses a backend json data file

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, web-scraping

I have a url which has some data about a person and the grades obtained in various subjects. Now I want to extract this data using python. So my basic approach was-

```py
import urllib.request
url='www.example.com'
webUrl  = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
data = webUrl.read()
print(data)
```

But instead of getting the data filled in some places in html, I realise that the url uses a json backend file and so what I get is like this-

```html
<span style="font-weight:700">Academic Session : {{y['student_detail_json'].Academic_Year}}
```

So it is basically useless if I just extract the html. So is there a way I can extract the data after the js has been executed. Selenium is one option, but I find it kind of heavy and if there is a more efficient way I'll be greatfull

Comment: Have you tried getting the JSON directly instead of the HTML?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón it was my first option but couldn't possibly do it

Comment: Why not? Isn't [this](https://spv.edunext1.com/mobile/ExamReportEngineUtility?academicyearid=5&classid=14&csectionid=46&studentdatafilter=2921&termid=64&is_subject_teacher_required=1&is_group_teacher_required=1) the JSON URL?

Comment: @HernánAlarcón oh yes thanks a ton!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access JSON. Simple example how.

```
import requests
url = "https://test.com"
payload = {}
headers = {}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, data = payload)
print(response.json())
```

Answer (score 0):

try chrome dev tools and find get request then try this:

It looks like you need to add a couple of headers, you can then access the json as you would normally e.g.

```
import requests
import json

headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:57.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/57.0', 'Accept': 'application/json; charset=utf-8'}
r = requests.get('https://stats.nba.com/stats/boxscoreplayertrackv2/?GameID=0021700300', headers=headers)

j =r.json()

for row in j['resultSets']:
    print (row['name'])
    for rowSet in row['rowSet']:
        print (rowSet)
```